# Regex space in string

Tags: php, regex

I want to get this code in regex but I am getting problem with the spaces between them so array doesn't show any thing because of spaces.

Example sting:

```
 dir="ltr"
        title="DRD Paratus-18 (Suit Case Gun)"
        data-sessionlink="ei=wpEsU4u8LZPI8gPK_YCwDQ&amp;ved=CEYQvxs"
```

I want to get the title using Regex like

```
 DRD Paratus-18 (Suit Case Gun)
```

So the regex I am using is something like that so tell me what to do with that space after ltr" and what's the correct regex

```
dir="ltr"         "title="(.*?)"
```

Comment: well, you could match one or more spaces like this: `\s+`

Answer (score 1):

What is the `"` doing here??

```
dir="ltr"         "title="(.*?)"
             here^^
```

Correct one will be:

```
dir="ltr"\s+title="(.*?)"
```